# Retrieving HTML file using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I have a Javascript application and I need to retrieve an HTML file to template it. The way I am doing this now is:

```
var _$e = null;
$.ajax({                               
  type: "GET",                         
  url: "/static/jobs_overview.html",   
  async: false,                        
  dataType: "xml",                     
  success: function (xml) {            
    _$e = $(xml.documentElement);      
  }                                    
});
```

This does seem to work, but for some reason, I am not getting a proper jQuery object in `_$e`. I know that because the styling is done by jQuery is getting lost at some point, but also, when I set a breakpoint in success, here is what I see:

```
> _$e
[<div class=​"hello" style=​"background-color:​#FFD700;​height:​200px;​width:​100px;​">​<p>​ Hi ​</p></div>​]
> _$e.width()
TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of null
```

However, when I copy the HTML string manually and convert it to a jQuery object as in `success`, the output is:

```
> $('<div class="hello" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;"><p> Hi </p></div>').width()
100
```

Seems like the xml object returned isn't getting converted properly into jQuery (or not all attributes of the object are being read properly by jQuery -- given that the HTML is rendering but styling isn't).

The xml object is:

```
> xml
#document
<div class=​"hello" style=​"background-color:​#FFD700;​height:​200px;​width:​100px;​">​…​</div>​
```

Any ideas how to get the xml (or the HTML file) rendered as a jQuery object properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because you're grabbing the datatype XML?   Have you tried setting your datatype to HTML (or nothing) and just do this (ignoring the .documentElement and just assuming the whole glomp is your HTML):

```
$.ajax({                               
  type: "GET",                         
  url: "/static/jobs_overview.html",   
  async: false,                        
  dataType: "html",                     
  success: function (data) {            
    _$e = $(data);              // we are getting back HTML, 
    console.log(_$e.width());   // jQuery is fine with html globs
  }                                    
});
```

Comment: Odd. That was a stupid question. I saw online a bunch of examples using xml so I used that. Pretty sure I then tried HTML but that did not work earlier, but now it did. Must have been something else that  broke it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are pulling it in as XML.  Try setting the `dataType` to `html` and see if that makes any difference.

It also sounds like `.load()` might better fit your needs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: `load()` isn't working. I also need to retrieve the HTML as a jQuery object. `load()` appears to attach the HTML to a DOM, element which is not what I want.

Comment: Ah, if you aren't attaching the HTML to the DOM, then the first one should work.